# Next step when DBCC CHECKDB REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS failes

Tags: sql-server, database, corruption, data-loss, dbcc

I'm in a situation where a few Tables of a Database (MSSQL2016 - 13.0.5081.1)
are corrupted (selecting data failes at some point)
There is no valid backup available (the error seems to be present in the DB for a long time) However, i finally end up by executing the `DBCC CHECKDB` command with the `REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS` option.
But this fails too. The output returns messages like the following a couple of times:

> Meldung 8909, Ebene 16, Status 1, Zeile 2
>   Tabellenfehler: Objekt-ID 0, Index-ID -1, Partitions-ID 0, Zuordnungseinheits-ID -7451885722783318016 (Unknown-Typ), Seiten-ID (1:290902) enthält eine falsche Seiten-ID im Seitenheader. PageId-Wert im Seitenheader = (9978:208048830).
>           Vor dem Beheben dieses Fehlers müssen zunächst andere Fehler behoben werden.

In english the message should be something like this...

> Table error: Object ID 0, index id -1, partition ID 0, allocation unit
>   ID -7451885722783318016 (unknown type), page id (1: 290902) contains
>   an incorrect page ID in the page header. PageId value in page header =
>   (9978: 208048830).
>            Before resolving this error, other errors must be resolved first.

**But  what does this mean:**

```
 Before resolving this error, other errors must be resolved first.
```

Which oher errors? - This messages returns a few times for differnt pages but no hint to other errors. I am aware that this whole situation will end up in dataloss.. i have to live with that.

Does anybody know how to step further?

**UPDATE:**

As in the comments mentioned i tried to evaluate the pageinfo with the `traceflag 3604` enabled:

> PAGE: (9978:208048830)
>
> BUFFER:
>
> BUF @0x000001D69F08F000
>
> bpage = 0x000001D440C64000          bhash = 0x0000000000000000
>   bpageno = (1:290902) bdbid = 12                          breferences =
>   0                     bcputicks = 0 bsampleCount = 0
>   bUse1 = 16138                       bstat = 0x809 blog = 0x1215a
>   bnext = 0x0000000000000000          bDirtyContext = 0x0000000000000000
>   bstat2 = 0x0
>
> PAGE HEADER:
>
> Page @0x000001D440C64000
>
> m_pageId = (9978:208048830)         m_headerVersion = 202
>   m_type = 214 m_typeFlagBits = 0x86               m_level = 148
>   m_flagBits = 0xe010 m_objId (AllocUnitId.idObj) = -1788167502
>   m_indexId (AllocUnitId.idInd) = 39061 Metadata: AllocUnitId =
>   -7451885722783318016                             Metadata: PartitionId = 0 Metadata: IndexId = -1              Metadata: ObjectId = 0              m_prevPage = (54490:-85112207) m_nextPage = (63487:2133407350)
>   pminlen = 44485                     m_slotCnt = 15506 m_freeCnt =
>   40634                   m_freeData = 52980
>   m_reservedCnt = 43709 m_lsn = (-1571835192:-1449823006:20555)
>   m_xactReserved = 12100 m_xdesId = (60082:-2118893827)
>   m_ghostRecCnt = 18723               m_tornBits = -1316355089 DB Frag
>   ID = 1
>
> Allocation Status
>
> GAM (1:2) = ALLOCATED               SGAM (1:3) = NOT ALLOCATED
>   PFS (1:283080) = 0x40 ALLOCATED   0_PCT_FULL
>   DIFF (1:6) = NOT CHANGED ML (1:7) = NOT MIN_LOGGED

The `m_type` returns a suspect value of `214` - which i'm unable to match to one the follow valid page types:

```
1 – data page
2 – index page
3 and 4 – text pages
8 – GAM page
9 – SGAM page
10 – IAM page
11 – PFS page
13 - Boot page
15 - File header page
16 - diff map apge
17 - ML map page
18 - deallocated page
19 - Temp page
20 - Pre-Allocated page für bulk operations
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try page restore rather than `REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS`? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-pages-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017 Also, what type of page is it? Do `dbcc traceon(3604); dbcc page('yourDBName', 1, 290902, 0);` and look for `m_type` in the output. You can find the decoder ring here: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-anatomy-of-a-page/.

Comment: @BenThul Thanks! Unfortunately, a page restore is not possible, because there is no backup available where the suspect pages are valid.. For the 'm_type' i have updated my question

Comment: Hmm... based on the information in https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/finding-table-name-page-id/, that object id of 0 is troubling.

Comment: @BenThul yea i see - but for my understandings... "object 0" is always invalid... normally ids for objects start with "1" in mssql...

Comment: You're right. But you've also got corruption, so there's something weird about that page. From the article, ObjectID = 0 could be 
    The table that the page was part of has been deleted since the page corruption was logged
    The system catalogs are corrupt in some way
    The page is corrupt and so incorrect values were used to look up the metadata